# Confusion Matrix to get precsion,recall, f1score

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe df. I have performed decisionTree classification algorithm on the dataframe. The two columns are label and features when algorithm is performed. The model is called `dtc`. How can I create a confusion matrix in pyspark?

```
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol = 'label')
dtcModel = dtc.fit(train)
predictions = dtcModel.transform(test)
```

````
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import MulticlassMetrics

preds = df.select(['label', 'features']) \
                            .df.map(lambda line: (line[1], line[0]))
metrics = MulticlassMetrics(preds)

    # Confusion Matrix
print(metrics.confusionMatrix().toArray())```
````

Answer (score 13):

You need to cast to an rdd and map to tuple before calling `metrics.confusionMatrix().toArray()`.

From the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html),

> class pyspark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels)[source]
>
> Evaluator for multiclass classification.
>
> Parameters: predictionAndLabels – an RDD of (prediction, label) pairs.

Here is an example to guide you.

ML part

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import MulticlassMetrics
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
#Note the differences between ml and mllib, they are two different libraries.

#create a sample data frame
data = [(1.54,3.45,2.56,0),(9.39,8.31,1.34,0),(1.25,3.31,9.87,1),(9.35,5.67,2.49,2),\
        (1.23,4.67,8.91,1),(3.56,9.08,7.45,2),(6.43,2.23,1.19,1),(7.89,5.32,9.08,2)]

cols = ('a','b','c','d')

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)

assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['a','b','c'], outputCol='features')

df_features = assembler.transform(df)

#df.show()

train_data, test_data = df_features.randomSplit([0.6,0.4])

dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(featuresCol='features',labelCol='d')

dtcModel = dtc.fit(train_data)

predictions = dtcModel.transform(test_data)
```

Evaluation part

```
#important: need to cast to float type, and order by prediction, else it won't work
preds_and_labels = predictions.select(['predictions','d']).withColumn('label', F.col('d').cast(FloatType())).orderBy('prediction')

#select only prediction and label columns
preds_and_labels = preds_and_labels.select(['prediction','label'])

metrics = MulticlassMetrics(preds_and_labels.rdd.map(tuple))

print(metrics.confusionMatrix().toArray())
```

Comment: Thanks, can you pls provide _Evaluation part_ for Spark-Scala. I was unable to do this `preds_and_labels.rdd.map(tuple)` in Scala.

Comment: I was able to make it work in Scala this way: `preds_and_labels.rdd.map(f=> (f.getAs[Double]("prediction"), f.getAs[Double]("label")))`

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
import sklearn 
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier

rf = RandomForestClassifier(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol = 'label', numTrees=500)
rfModel = rf.fit(train)
predictions_train = rfModel.transform(train)

y_true = predictions_train.select(['label']).collect()
y_pred = predictions_train.select(['prediction']).collect()

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
```

where `train` is your training data.

Comment: If the dataset is huge and cannot fit into memory, how are you going to collect it and pass it to confusion_matrix() ?